# overriding bootstrap link - focus

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap framework and am trying to override some of its features. I have it working except one. I am trying to remove the background when a link is clicked. Right now the link is clicked and a grey background is shown behind. The problem also is that the link just goes to the bottom of the same page.

I have been able to remove the issue with the following code, however, doing it this way makes the background not show up on hover (the link remains active when clicked)

```
.navbar-custom .nav>li>a:hover { 
color: #585858;
background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-custom .nav>li>a:focus {
background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: the links are handled in wordpress, The html only shows the default bootstrap html not the links.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you should be able to replace `:focus` with `:active` to solve your problem:

```
.navbar-custom .nav>li>a:active {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: i thought that to, forgot to mention i tried that, but when i use active the background comes back. I have that code line in my css already